# C++ vector<T>::iterator operator +

Tags: c++, iterator, operators

Im holding an iterator that points to an element of a vector, and I would like to compare it to the next element of the vector.

Here is what I have

```
Class Point{
public:
 float x,y;
}

//Somewhere in my code I do this

vector<Point> points = line.getPoints();

foo (points.begin(),points.end());
```

where foo is:

```
void foo (Vector<Point>::iterator begin,Vector<Point>::iterator end)
{
    std::Vector<Point>::iterator current = begin;

    for(;current!=end-1;++current)
    {
        std::Vector<Point>::iterator next = current + 1;

        //Compare between current and next.
    }
}
```

I thought that this would work, but `current + 1` is not giving me the next element of the vector.

I though operator+ was the way to go, but doesnt seem so. Is there a workaround on this?

THanks

Comment: Could you show more detail about why you think `next` isn't referring to the element after current?

Comment: Can you clarify "but current + 1 is not giving me the next element of the vector." ?

Comment: Just a small sidenote: you need to say `typename Vector<Point>::iterator begin` ( and `end`, and `current`). Even if the code compiles as is, the standard doesn't require it to. In general, whenever you have `class_template<T>::some_type obj` you have to prefix it with `typename` to make sure the compiler understands `some_type` is a type and not something else.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: No, the standard doesn't require that, unless `Point` were a template parameter. TTBOMK, C++98 even _disallows_ you using `typename` for a non-dependent type. (ISTR litb explaining that C++03 allows it, but I'm not sure and at least one popular current compiler clearly disallows it.)

Comment: @wilhelmtell - not correct.  You only need to use typename when the type is dependent on another template parameter.  i.e. `template <class T> typename vector<T>::iterator ...`

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was a silly mistake, but answers were helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current + 1` is valid for random access iterators (which include vector iterators), and it is the iterator after current (i.e., what you think it does). Check (or post!) your comparison code, you're probably doing something wrong in there.

Comment: Indeed. The solution? 1) Asking on S.O, 2) Getting some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` has *random-access* iterators. That means they are, basically, as versatile as pointers. They provide full-blown pointer arithmetic (`it+5`, `it+=2`) and comparisons other than `!=`/`==` (i.e., `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`).

Comparison between iterators in your code should certainly work, but would be nonsensical:

```
for(std::vector<Point>::iterator current = begin;current!=end-1;++current)
{
    std::vector<Point>::iterator next = current + 1;

    assert(current!=next); // always true
    assert(current<next); // also always true
}
```

So if it doesn't work for you, it's likely you do something wrong. Unfortunately, "...is not giving me the next element of the vector..." doesn't give us no clue what you are trying, so it's hard to guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: current shouldn't point to the last element in this loop, though a check for `begin != end` might be in order.

Comment: @visitor: Yeah, you're right. I copied the loops ending condition without even looking at it. `<sigh>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a typo, but your code is referring to `Vector` while the standard container is `vector` (lower case V).

But if that's not a typo in your question, without seeing the definition of `Vector`, there's no way to tell what that does.